# How there can be an explicit coordinate dependence on the Lagrangian, if this arises from a Lagrangian density?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, spacetime, field-theory, coordinate-systems

I have a very simple question, but strangely I cannot find any answer on the internet; maybe the answer is too simple that I don't notice. I go straight to the point: if I define a Lagrangian from a Lagrangian density, and so from a *definite integral* in the coordinate space, how there can be an explicit coordinate dependence on the Lagrangian? In the picture I try to calculate the action along a *fixed* $s$-parametrized trajectory  in the $n+1$-dimensional space in which a scalar field $\phi$ is present ($y_i$ is the generical $i$-component of the $n+1$-dimensional vector $\boldsymbol{y}=(\boldsymbol{x},t)$ ).

\begin{equation}
S\boldsymbol{=}\int\limits_{t\left(s_1\right)}^{t\left(s_2\right)}\!\!\!\!\mathrm dt\,L\left(\boldsymbol{x}\left(s\right),t\left(s\right)\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\right)\boldsymbol{\doteq}\!\!\int\limits_{t\left(s_1\right)}^{t\left(s_2\right)}\!\!\!\!\mathrm dt\!\!\int\limits_{\mathcal M_n}\!\!\mathrm d^n x\,\mathscr L\left(\phi,\{\partial_{y_{i}}\phi\},\boldsymbol{x},t\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\right) 
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}

I don't know if it is a stupid question, but this indetermination on what actually is the nature of the quantities I've got in front of me, completely mess my conception up, about what I can and what I can't do, such as when is the case to treat total and partial derivatives in the coordinate, of the lagrangian density; so thanks really in advance to anyone that will answer!

Comment: What's your source? What is exactly the manifold (???} $\mathcal M_{n}$ ???

Comment: I know to be very unclear when I ask questions, sorry. In this case what I'm actually asking is "if I have a lagrangian $L$ depending on spacetime index $\boldsymbol{x}$, can it arise from a lagrangian density $\mathscr{L}$, or not?". So to me the point is to get an analogy with the general relativity, if I would check my notes again in the future: I was trying to be the more general possible, and I considered an $n+1$-dimensional manifold, instead of a global flat spacetime, that's all, but if you want, that's just notation in the context of the question.

Comment: I think the relativistic discussion is really complicate when I want an integral from a point $\boldsymbol{x}_0$ to another point $\boldsymbol{x}$, so at the moment I'm just interested in the flat spacetime case, to understand if it is possible to define $L(\boldsymbol{x},...)=\int_{\boldsymbol{x}_0}^{\boldsymbol{x}}\text{d}^n\tilde{x}\mathscr{L}(\tilde{\boldsymbol{x}},...)$

Answer (score 0):

OP's equation is a bit unclear. In this answer we will for simplicity only consider the case where OP's $s$-parametrization is spacetime-filling, i.e. $s=n+1$. Also to be concrete, let $n=3$. Then we are back at standard field theory in 3+1D.

In that case the [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory)) $$\begin{align}L_V[q(\cdot,t);v(\cdot,t);t]~:=~&\int_V\!  d^3x~ {\cal L}\left(q(\vec{x},t);v(\vec{x},t),\frac{\partial q(\vec{x},t)}{\partial \vec{x}};\vec{x},t\right),\cr  v(\vec{x},t)~:=~&\frac{d q(\vec{x},t)}{d t},\end{align}\tag{A}$$
can still depend explicitly on time $t\in [t_i,t_f]$. It can obviously not depend on the integration variable $\vec{x}$. However it can in principle depend on the spatial positions of the spatial boundary $\partial V$ of the spatial volume $V$. Here
$$\underbrace{V\times [t_i,t_f]}_{\text{spacetime}}\quad\stackrel{q}{\longrightarrow}\quad \underbrace{M}_{\text{target space}}.\tag{B}$$

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. Ok, I get what you say, but what happens when a lagrangian *actually* depends on the "spatial" coordinates? Does it mean that it cannot be conceived as arising from an integration of the lagrangian density? Or this integration is not on the actual spatial boundaries of the system, but stops at $\boldsymbol{x}$, so it is like an indefinite integral? I hope it is clear what I said and it's not too unreasonable

Comment: Perhaps your "spatial" coordinates are living in the target space?

Comment: With "target space" do you mean the image of $V\times[t_i,t_f]$ trough the scalar field $q$? Because, sorry, I don't understand your question; if so this target space should be $\mathbb{R}$ I think. What I imagine, is to be in a space with $n$ dimensions, plus $1$ temporal dimension and I just want to understand how a lagrangian can have an explicit dependence on $\boldsymbol{x}$ if it emerges from a definite integral.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes to the first question in above comment.

Comment: Ok, but sorry I continue to don't understand how a lagrangian can have an explicit dependence on $\boldsymbol{x}$

Comment: "It can obviously not depend on the integration variable x"
Why not? This seems to be the core of the question, and it is not obvious to me either. What is reason for this?

Comment: I'm just saying things like "$\int_1^2 \! dx~ x^3 $ does not depend on $x$", but I could have misunderstood what OP is asking.

Comment: @Qmechanic  You understood what I asked, thanks again. What I still don't understand is if instead of the total integration domain $\mathcal{M}_n$ in spatial indices, I can use something else depending on $\boldsymbol{x}$.